# How to use insert with for in?

Tags: swift

have a problems with adding elements from 1 array to another

```
var fruits = ["Apples", "Orange", "Banana"]
var vegetables = ["Potato", "Carrot", "Tomato"]
var food = vegetables
```

I need to add Apples and Oranges to array food and they have to be under index 0 and 1

so I try to do it like that

```
for fruit in fruits {
       food.insert("Apples", at:0)
       food.insert("Orange", at:1)
}
```

When I try to print it it gives me Apple Apple Orange Orange Potato Carrot Tomato
How to fix it?

Comment: yes without for in it's working but the problem is that the task that I have is to use for in and insert so this is confusing me

Comment: What output do you wish to get? What's the logic here, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the for-in loop but don't want to add 'Banana', then you should add the elements of the array.

So your code should look like this:

```
var fruits = ["Apples", "Orange", "Banana"]
var vegetables = ["Potato", "Carrot", "Tomato"]
var food = vegetables

for fruit in fruits {
       if fruits.firstIndex(of:fruit)! < 2 {
            food.insert(fruit, at: fruits.firstIndex(of:fruit)!)
       }
}
```

`firstIndex` finds the first occurrence of that element in the array and returns either its position or `nil`, if the element is not in the array.

We need the `!` to force-unwrap the return value of `firstIndex` since we know it will not be `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the loop insert the `fruit` **index variable** if it's not `Banana`

```
var fruits = ["Apples", "Orange", "Banana"]
var vegetables = ["Potato", "Carrot", "Tomato"]
var food = vegetables

for fruit in fruits where fruit != "Banana" {
    food.insert(fruit, at:0)
}
```

Or if you just want to merge the arrays

```
var food = fruits + vegetables
```

Comment: thank you! and if there is no banana in the array, just apples and oranges?

Comment: Then delete the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is

```
food = fruits.prefix(2) + vegetables
```

And one with a loop

```
for index in fruits.indices where index < 2 {
    guard index < food.count else { break }
    food.insert(fruits[index], at: index)
}

// or instead of guard: index < food.count ? food.insert(fruits[index], at: index) : food.append(fruits[index])
```